# Is possible to capture images dynamically in sikuli?

Tags: python, sikuli

I am using sikuli to load IE and from that i am opening the .flv records from adobe connect.In that i have capture images dynamically and have to store that images in a list object or any data structure. Is it possible to capture images from a window dynamically in sikuli?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Your english is a little unclear to me.  Tell me if this is correct: you are downloading a video in .flv format and playing it in Adobe Connect.  You want to know if you can capture images from this video using Sikuli?

Comment: Hi, Ya i want to capture images dynamically from video when it is running.

Comment: Are you able to manually do a screen-capture when the video's running? If your video player has DRM to block that, then Sikuli probably won't be able to help.  Otherwise, you can do it.  Do you need to capture periodically?  Like, every `n` seconds?  Or is there some other capture trigger?

Comment: Hi,i am  able to get image text while running sikuli. Its resolved.

Comment: If you describe the solution that worked for you as an answer, you can then mark that as accepted and it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
def CaptureScreen(path):
    #Take Screen shot and move it from temp folder to new location <path>
    shutil.move(capture(Screen()), path)
```

http://doc.sikuli.org/screen.html#Screen.capture

http://www.jython.org/docs/library/shutil.html